# How to add New Activities to Navigation Drawer in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

I added one fragment(travel) to navigation drawer.So I want to add some activities(act 1,act 2) also..I don't know how to do it.Can you help me to resolve it....I added to xml file.But I dont know how to do it in java code.Thank You.

**Here is my drawer.xml code**

```
 <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Travle"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
            android:title="Travel Fragment" />
      </group>

    <item android:title="More">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_activity1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_act_e"
                android:title="Activity 1" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_activity2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_act_s"
                android:title="Activity 2" />
  </menu>
    </item>
```

**Here is my drawer code....**

```
  @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_blood:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new Aboutus()).commit();
                break;
        }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You can just add more menus in menu.xml file and create Fragments related to those menu items. You don't have to create another activity for new menu, just replace fragments n menu item selection.

Comment: hello @Mr.Soft please post your activity xml code than after i will tell you what is happen between activity and fragment with drawer

Comment: Thanks for reply.I found the answer..Here it is,
case R.id.nav_activity1:
                Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,activity1.class);
                       startActivity(a);
                break;

Comment: But in new opened activity you can't get the navigation drawer for that you need to go back keep in mind that.
best of luck

Comment: @NileshPanchal Oh gosh...that's right.But I'm going to add scrolling activity.It's possible to add drawer toggle icon to that ?